# Can two enums not have a member of similar name?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I have a situation where I need two enums to hold one member of the same name. My code is in C++, Using *IAR Embeddedj Workbench* IDE. The code snippet is as follows:

```
enum Port_e : uint32_t
{
    PortA = 0,
    PortB,
    PortC,
    PortD,
    PortE,
    PortF,
    PortG,
    PortH,
    PortI,
    PortJ,
    PortK,
    NONE
};

enum Pin_e : uint32_t
{
    Pin0 = 0, Pin1, Pin2, Pin3, Pin4, Pin5, Pin6, Pin7,
    Pin8, Pin9, Pin10, Pin11, Pin12, Pin13, Pin14, Pin15,NONE
};
```

If you notice here both enums have the last member as **NONE**.
This code does not compile. Gives Error as **NONE** is already defined.

Is there any way to make it build while keeping the name as it is?
I also do not want to change the type to "enum class" as it will break the rest of my application code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to make it build while keeping name as it is?

Not without changes. If you wrap `Port_e` and `Pin_e` in a namespace or class you can resolve the name collision, but that would still alter the way the enums are used.

> I also do not want to change the type to "enum class" as it will break the rest of my application code.

I strongly suggest you to do that anyway, and take the time to fix your application code. `enum class` was designed exactly to solve this problem.

Comment: I'll wrap your enum in a namespace.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: sorry, but my enum is declared under `private`. You have no access to it.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo thanks for your response. You got very valid point here about enum class I will look into that. Just to elaborate these both enums are in same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class enums or  nest your enums  in appropriate classes or namespaces.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class A :uint32_t { One, Two, Three };
enum class B :uint32_t { One, Two, Three };

int main()
{
    std::cout << int(A::One) << std::endl;
}
```

Identifiers of enumeration are names of integral constants belonging to namespace enum is declared in. Class enums changed this situation, but you cant cast from and to them implicitly. Any other approach eventually would cause ODR breakage if you would use simple enogh names. In your code it leads to ambiguity: is NONE equal to 13? Or to 16?